# How do I add artists to the Ubuntu One store?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Several of my friends are in bands and looking at different means to distribute their music. What's the procedure for getting an Artist added to the Ubuntu One Music store? Costs, exclusiveness, contracts, profit sharing, etc?

Is there a minimum price for a song or is that up to the artist/label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

7digital manages the catalogue of songs. As far as I know, past the branding and sales kickbacks, Canonical has very little to do with its running.

If you want something adding, you'll needed it added to 7digital's main catalogue. To do that you'll need to contact 7digital's business arm and work out a deal (where you can also get answers for your other sub-questions).

They have a separate contact page (and website for that matter) for business-related queries here:

http://about.7digital.net/Contacts